# jQuery val() only returns value when input box set by user

Tags: jquery

If I manually enter text into an input element, I can call `$("#myinput").val()` and get a value.

If I set it first like `$("#myinput").val("foo")` and then call `$("#myinput").val()`, it returns nothing.

Comment: Does `$("input")` refer to the same element as `$("#myinput")`?

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. They're all the same selector.

Comment: @espekia - If the selectors are the same, there's no reason it wouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have only **one** input on the page with `id="myinput"`

---

#### Answer Based on Original Question:

`$("input").val()` returns the value of the **first** input of the page

if `#myinput` is not first, it will not be shown.

---

To get **all** the vals of **all** the inputs on the page you can do:

```
$('input').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry, typo. It was supposed to be $("#myinput").val()

Comment: make sure you have an input on the page with `id="myinput"`

Answer (score 1):

Call `$("#myinput").val()` in second case too.
The matter is `$("input").val()` returns the first input's value ([jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)).

**EDIT:**
After your correct, I can only say, that I believe it should work, because you're using 2 same selectors in both cases.
May be, you have some code, that modifies value between these calls. Or may be you have more than one input with the same **id**..

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple inputs on the page, then it won't return a value because `$('input')` is an array of inputs.

You'll have to do something like

```
$('input').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

to show all vals.  Otherwise, use `$('#myInput').val();`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
<input id="i" />
```

JS

```
$('#i').val('hi');
console.log($('#i').val());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/mpjmT/

You may have a condition statement in your code that prevent the set value line runs.